# How can I use @media queries if some phones have higher resolution than computers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I see people saying to use @media queries to change css if someone is on mobile, but how can I use this if my phone has 1440p width while my computer has 1920?  Should I make anything under 1440p have phone styling?

Comment: I found [this page](http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/7-habits-of-highly-effective-media-queries/) very useful in answering this question. Don't think so much of specific form factors or screen widths... Rather, think of screen width as an area into which you can progressively enhance your page.

Comment: ["Start with the small screen first, then expand until it looks like s**t. Time for a breakpoint! "](http://bradfrost.com/blog/mobile/bdconf-stephen-hay-presents-responsive-design-workflow/)

Answer (score 1):

A phone is going to have a higher pixel density. If you add this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
to your head then it will take pixel density into account.

As an example, it may treat a 1000px wide phone as a 400px wide phone.

Comment: This is not really true. The pixel dimensions that browsers expose in phones are the dimensions *after* the "retina" style compression. So, the actual native pixel dimension may be some large number, but the browser on the phone will tell JavaScript and CSS that the width/height is some fraction of that.

Comment: The `<meta>` thing has no effect on the way that works. It does have an effect, but it's something different.

Comment: Much better! By setting the viewport width equal to “device-width”, we’re essentially telling it that the device width is 320px, not the default value of 980px that it guessed. If we set width=320 it would achieve the same result on the iPhone and a few other smartphones, but not all phones have this exact width, so it’s best to simply set device-width and let the mobile browser figure it out.

Comment: I know what the viewport tag does. It has nothing to do with how the browser maps actual physical device pixel resolution into the resolution reported by browser APIs.

Comment: Browsers don't "guess" the device width. They *know* it, because they're native applications.

Comment: I got that quote above from this link http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/viewport-metatag/ Here is a better link that talks about pixel density https://ariya.io/2011/08/mobile-web-logical-pixel-vs-physical-pixel

Comment: Again, I am familiar with the difference between physical pixel density and browser-reported screen resolution. The actual pixel density is something that the browser won't tell you.